# didSwipedCardAtIndex Koloda pod didn't work

Tags: koloda

Good afternoon guys!

No one can help me - I have this problem on the pod 'Koloda', '4.6' version and I don’t know what to do.

didSwipeCardAtIndex not called by delegate. Previously, on swift 2 everything worked fine. Now Swift 3 & 4 Sample didn't call func too... https://github.com/Yalantis/Koloda

```
func koloda(koloda: KolodaView, didSwipedCardAtIndex index: UInt, inDirection direction: SwipeResultDirection) {
    //
}
```

Thanks for all

Answer (score 0):

You can use this function in swift 4

```
func koloda(koloda: KolodaView, shouldSwipeCardAtIndex index: UInt, inDirection direction: SwipeResultDirection) -> Bool {

        if direction == SwipeResultDirection.left || direction == SwipeResultDirection.right {
            return true
        }

        return false
    }
```